# Как в PhpStorm закрыть левый toolbar menu оставив остальные?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm, ide, webstorm

в PhpStorm нужно закрыть неиспользуемый левый toolbar menu оставив остальные, как можно это сделать ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно просто перетянуть вкладки (в вашем случае — это «Projects», «Pull Requests», «Repositories», «Favorites» & «Structure») на нужную сторону:

[image: Скриншот]